# Let a, b, q, r be integers, with b $\neq$ 0, and assume that a = bq + r. Then gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, r).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I'm aware of the proof of this statement. However, the proof simply shows that some integer $d$ is a common divisor. But how does it being a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, $b$ and $r$ show that it is the **greatest** common divisor?

Comment: Which proof are you aware of?

Answer (score -1):

The existence of the common divisor $d$ of any $2$ integers, say $a, b$ assume that they both be different from $0$ comes from the unique prime factorization of both $a,b$. If $a = p_1^{n_1}\cdot p_2^{n_2}\cdots p_m^{n_m}, b = q_1^{s_1}\cdot q_2^{s_2}\cdots q_k^{s_k}$ whereas the $p_i, q_j$ are primes and $n_i, s_j$ are naturals. Then if some $i, j$ such that $p_i = q_j$, then $d$ exists and $d = p_i^{\text{min}(n_i,s_j)}$ is a common divisor since $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b$. If not, then $d = 1$. Among all the common divisors of $a, b$, we can take the largest and call it $\text{gcd}(a,b)$. For the sake of notation, let $d = \text{gcd}(a,b)$, then $d \mid a$, $d \mid b$, so $d \mid (a  - bq)$, and hence $d \mid r$. So $d \mid  \text{gcd}(b,r)$. If $f = \text{gcd}(b,r)$, then $f \mid b$, $f \mid r$, then $f \mid (bq+r)$ or $f \mid a$. Thus $f \mid \text{gcd}(a,b)$. In brief, we have shown that $\text{gcd}(a,b) \mid \text{gcd}(b,r)$ and $\text{gcd}(b,r) \mid \text{gcd}(a,b) \implies \text{gcd}(a,b) = \text{gcd}(b,r)$.

Comment: I don't follow how $d|r$ implies $d|gcd(b,r)$

Comment: Because $d \mid b$, and $d \mid r$, so $d \mid \text{gcd}(b,r)$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).